# Port Mongoose web server to FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, mongoose-web-server

I was wondering if anyone had success in porting the Linux versions of the Mongoose web server or the Civetweb web server to FreeBSD. I've tried to do a Make, but there is a compatibility issue between Linux and BSD, in that it cannot find -ldl.  I've seen reference to this in a google search, and the recommended solution is probably beyond my skill level.

Comment: I think question more related to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux uses GNU make by default. Its makefiles tend to be incompatible with FreeBSD's make. So you need to install GNU make using the `/usr/ports/devel/gmake` port. The program is called `gmake` on FreeBSD.

So for mongoose, download the latest mongoose source from github.
Then install GNU make using the `/usr/ports/devel/gmake` port. Unpack mongoose;

```
> tar xf mongoose-5.3.tar.gz
> cd mongoose-5.3/examples
```

Then compile it;

```
> gmake
cc hello.c ../mongoose.c -o hello -W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g -pipe 
perl mkdata.pl websocket.html > websocket_html.c
cc websocket.c websocket_html.c ../mongoose.c -o websocket  -W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g -pipe 
cc server.c ../mongoose.c -o server  -W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g -pipe 
cc post.c ../mongoose.c -o post -W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g -pipe 
cc multi_threaded.c ../mongoose.c -o multi_threaded -W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g -pipe 
cc upload.c ../mongoose.c -o upload -W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g -pipe 
cc auth.c ../mongoose.c -o auth -W -Wall -I.. -pthread -g -pipe
```

Civetweb also compiles without errors using `gmake`.